# Where in Palma Majorca is it possible to sleep on the beach?

Tags: spain, camping, beaches, mediterranean, mallorca

My previous question was on [Canary Islands](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/on-which-canary-island-is-it-possible-to-sleep-on-the-beach), but now am asking the same thing about Palma.

We are planning a two-night trip to Palma Majorca (PMI airport we are flying to). Travel dates are last week of November, so I guess weather should be okay. I have never been to these islands. I'd like to sleep on the beach in a tent or mattresses. Is that possible, safety, legality, and weather? It would also be nice to know how populated with tourists the islands are.
Also what are some nice areas where if sleeping is hard , walking is nice. Nice meaning peaceful and quiet.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, but related to the question on Canary islands.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is legal to sleep on the beach in general? (A short Google search indicates that it is not) Or are you asking whether it's possible somewhere (where one might have to pay for it)?

Comment: @martin.koeberl of course it might not be entirely legal, but there might be areas where it is less likely to get caught than others. 2. I want to know good areas where it is possible to spend the entire night walking on the beach without too many people

Comment: Are you planning to sleep on the beach or to take a walk there? It would be good if you know what you want to ask. 
Also, what do you mean by "how populated with tourists"? Do you just want to know the number of tourists coming to visit Mallorca every year? It would be helpful if your question was a little more specific.

Comment: Are you asking about the Balearic islands in general, Mallorca, or Palma de Mallorca? The question seems to treat them indiscriminately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/104604/6997) to your previous, similar question, [On which Canary island is it possible to sleep on the beach?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/104571/6997),

> Camping and sleeping in the beach is not easy. Moreover, it is forbidden in most of Spanish coast apart from some exceptions.

However, there are some exceptions detailed in [7 playas donde puedes acampar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/104604/6997) that is, *7 beaches where you can camp*. In there it talks about **S'Arenalet, in Mallorca** (in Spanish, my translation):

> Even though in Mallorca free camping is not allowed, you can practice something similar in specific areas. One of the most genuine and less tamed is the area of s'Arenalet d'Aubarca, within the Parc Natural de Llevant (Natural Park of Llevant). Next to the shelter, you should put your tent in the terrain that is cooled by a pine forest.

Note, however, that Majorca has a worse weather than Canary Islands. Since it is in the Belearic Islands it won't be cold, but November can be cool at least. So sleeping in a tent may require some doses of thick clothes to spend the night.

[Holiday weather](http://www.holiday-weather.com/majorca/averages/november/) reports average temperatures of about 14ºC in November, short days (7 hours) and a low chance of getting rain (6 days per month).

---

By the way:

- Palma: the capital city of Majorca
- Majorca: the name of the island that is mostly used in English
- Mallorca: its official name and also its name in Catalan and Spanish
- Balearic islands: set of islands in which Majorca is the biggest. Others are Minorca, Ibiza, Formentera...

Comment: What's the difference in Mallorca and Majorca?

Comment: @bissi they are the same. Its official name is _Mallorca_,  only that in English they tend to use _Majorca_ to mimic the sound of the name in Catalan.

Comment: The spelling *Majorca* might not be to imitate the sound in Catalan but simply because it has evolved less in English than in Mallorquín. In Latin it seems to have been Maiorca.